# Html in RadGrid Footer

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, radgrid

Could someone tell me how to put some html into RadGrid footer? I need to put it not into column footer, but to one for entire grid.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid" ShowFooter="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">             
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <FooterStyle BorderWidth="10px" BorderColor="Red" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

There is no `<FooterTemplate>` tag for "global" footer, so maybe somebody knows the elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I didn't see that as an option.  The only thing I can think of, which I haven't verified, is:

- Try to set a column span on the first column's cell; the RadGrid is essentially a table-based structure, and on itemcreated or itemdatabound, when the row type is a footer, you could try setting the column span on that cell.
- You could try hiding the default footer, and put your own DIV at the bottom of the grid, with your additional contents.  You should be able to place a DIV right against the bottom of the grid.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that was both ways I've already implied. I thought maybe there is another way to do that, closer to telerik's declaritive manner. But once again - many thanks - you have enshured me, that that was right solution.